# Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, pip, zsh

What does it mean when I keep getting these warnings

WARNING: The script jupyter-trust is installed in '/Users/josephchoi/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

I am on MacOS and zsh. I tried researching but the texts were too complicated. As you can tell, I am a complete beginner.

Answer (score 3):

This normally will happen when you've installed a pip package that contains an executable, and it shouldn't be a problem. If you don't like the warning, you can add the folder to your PATH variable by adding the line `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/josephchoi/Library/Python/3.9/bin` to your .zshrc file in your home directory and it will stop shouting at you.

Comment: if this normally happens, then why would they design it such that it outputs a warning message? Also, thank you for answering. I was stressing over this for the past month, and I couldn't read this until recently because I was banned from stackoverflow for a period of time.